# Passing command line arguments to Spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark job written in scala. I use

```
spark-shell -i <file-name>
```

to run the job. I need to pass a command-line argument to the job. Right now, I invoke the script through a linux task, where I do

```
export INPUT_DATE=2015/04/27
```

and use the environment variable option to access the value using:

```
System.getenv("INPUT_DATE")
```

Is there a better way to handle the command line arguments in Spark-shell?

Comment: why would you want to pass an argument in spark-shell?!? why don't you use the spark-submit script to run the job normally??

Comment: Still running 0.9.1in CDH 4.6. spark-submit not available yet.

Comment: Another reason why you'd want to do that is to avoid the hassle of building a project if you are only running a 2-line scala code. See my answer below as to how I solved this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Short answer:

`spark-shell -i <(echo val theDate = $INPUT_DATE ; cat <file-name>)`

### Long answer:

This solution causes the following line to be added at the beginning of the file before passed to `spark-submit`:

`val theDate = ...`,

thereby defining a new variable. The way this is done (the `<( ... )` syntax) is called process substitution. It is available in Bash. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569730/paste-without-temporary-files-in-unix) for more on this, and for alternatives (e.g. `mkFifo`) for non-Bash environments.

#### Making this more systematic:

Put the code below in a script (e.g. `spark-script.sh`), and then you can simply use:

`./spark-script.sh your_file.scala first_arg second_arg third_arg`,
and have an `Array[String]` called `args` with your arguments.

The file `spark-script.sh`:

```
scala_file=$1

shift 1

arguments=$@

#set +o posix  # to enable process substitution when not running on bash 

spark-shell  --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
         --queue default \
        --driver-memory 2G --executor-memory 4G \
        --num-executors 10 \
        -i <(echo 'val args = "'$arguments'".split("\\s+")' ; cat $scala_file)
```

Comment: is there a better way to do it? can I pass the arguments like:  spark-shell -i script.scala args1 args2; so that in the scala file, i can retrieve the argument like args(1), args(2). this is a scala solution from http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-shell-script-command-line-arguments-args. however, it doesn't work in spark-shell. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 45):

My solution is use a customized key to define arguments instead of `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`, in case someday you pass in a value that may interfere JVM's behavior.

```
spark-shell -i your_script.scala --conf spark.driver.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

You can access the arguments from within your scala code like this:

```
val args = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")
args: Array[String] = Array(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: nice. slightly cleaner than `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`.

Comment: Actually you can do something easier with -conf spark.driver.arg1 -conf spark.driver.arg2 it seems that all configs prefixed with spark.driver are passed to the driver

Answer (score 10):

I use the `extraJavaOptions` when I have a scala script which is too simple to go through the build process but I still need to pass arguments to it. It's not beautiful, but it works and you can quickly pass multiple arguments:

```
spark-shell -i your_script.scala --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Darg1,arg2,arg3"
```

Note that `-D` does not belong to the arguments, which are `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`. You can then access the arguments from within your scala code like this:

```
val sconf = new SparkConf()

// load string
val paramsString = sconf.get("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions")

// cut off `-D`
val paramsSlice = paramsString.slice(2,paramsString.length)

// split the string with `,` as delimiter and save the result to an array
val paramsArray = paramsSlice.split(",")

// access parameters
val arg1 = paramsArray(0)
```

Comment: Include import statement: import org.apache.spark.SparkConf