# pass scala commands in bash script

Tags: bash, scala, shell

I am currently working on Apache spark. I want to see the time taken by the system to perform wordcount on a text file and store it in a file. I need to automate the commands with a bash script. I tried to run the following script :-

```
start-all.sh
    (time spark-shell 
     val inputfile = sc.textFile("/home/pi/Desktop/dataset/books_50.txt")
     val counts = inputfile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_);
     counts.toDebugString
     counts.cache()
     counts.saveAsTextFile("output")
     exit()
     ) 2> /home/pi/Desktop/spark_output/test.txt
stop-all.sh
```

For which it showed the following error:-

```
./wordcount_spark.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./wordcount_spark.sh: line 4: ` val inputfile = sc.textFile("/home/pi/Desktop/dataset/books_50.txt")'
```

I tried to add EOF to the code and I got the following error:-

```
./wordcount_spark.sh: line 12: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./wordcount_spark.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I didn't understand how to pass scala commands through a bash script

Comment: run it with `spark-sehll -i` option - here is an example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928999/passing-command-line-arguments-to-spark-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark-shell is an *interactive* tool, meant to be used interactively by a user typing one command after the other, so it's ill-fitting for your needs.

You should take a look at the [Self-Contained Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) section in Spark's Quick Start guide - which guides you how to write and build a simple Scala application, and execute it using **`spark-submit`**. That should better fit your requirement.