# Passing command line arguments to Spark-shell hangs on scala terminal

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark

I have a spark job written in scala. I use:

```
arguments=$@
spark-shell -i <file-name-with-main, 
        auxiliary-file-name1, auxiliary-file-name2> 
    --master yarn-client 
    --driver-memory 2G 
    --executor-memory 4G 
    --num-executors 10   
    --executor-cores 4 
 <(echo 'val args = "'$arguments'".split("\\s+")' ; 
   echo "main(args)"; 
   echo ':q')
```

to run the job. I got the idea from [Passing command line arguments to Spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928999/passing-command-line-arguments-to-spark-shell#).
But I need to include  echo "main(args)"; echo 'sys.exit' for it to work, and as otherwise it hangs on the scala terminal.

Why is that? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why are you not using Spark submit? Yes, spark-shell is interpreting a file, and *leaving you in the REPL*

Comment: I want the node I run the job from to act as driver, so that is why I use spark-shell.

Comment: If you want the node you run from to act as the driver just add "deploy-mode client" to your args to the spark-submit